# Ionic push notification Application

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, push-notification

I am working on ionic project where i have to implement push notification
but practically what to do i have  no idea
again my app is going to be used in corporate environment 
so what to do .
Kindly suggest.

Comment: https://devdactic.com/ionic-push-notifications/  here is the guid and the this link is a demo for ionic pushnotification http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Hello Rigel,
>
> Then first of all you have to install FOUR Plugins for that.
>
> 1)cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin
> // For notification
>
> 2)cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
> // For on Device Ready to call
>
> 3)cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs
> // For notification Dialog
>
> 4)cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media
> // For Notification Sound
> ```

and generate API key and SenderId throw developer console.and senderid past in bellow code. And e.regid pass to on server.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="PushNotification.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var pushNotification;

            function onDeviceReady() {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>deviceready event received</li>');

                document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e)
                {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>backbutton event received</li>');

                    if( $("#home").length > 0)
                    {
                        // call this to get a new token each time. don't call it to reuse existing token.
                        //pushNotification.unregister(successHandler, errorHandler);
                        e.preventDefault();
                        navigator.app.exitApp();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        navigator.app.backHistory();
                    }
                }, false);

                try 
                { 
                    pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
              $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering ' + device.platform + '</li>');
                    if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' ||
                            device.platform == 'amazon-fireos' ) {
            pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"661780372179","ecb":"onNotification"});        // required!
                    } else {
                        pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});    // required!
                    }
                }
                catch(err) 
                { 
                    txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n"; 
                    txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n"; 
                    alert(txt); 
                } 
            }

            // handle APNS notifications for iOS
            function onNotificationAPN(e) {
                if (e.alert) {
                     $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>push-notification: ' + e.alert + '</li>');
                     // showing an alert also requires the org.apache.cordova.dialogs plugin
                     navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
                }

                if (e.sound) {
                    // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
                    var snd = new Media(e.sound);
                    snd.play();
                }

                if (e.badge) {
                    pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
                }
            }

            // handle GCM notifications for Android
            function onNotification(e) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

                switch( e.event )
                {
                    case 'registered':
                    if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                    {
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                        // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                        // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                        console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
                    }
                    break;

                    case 'message':
                        // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
                        // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
                        if (e.foreground)
                        {
                            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');

                                // on Android soundname is outside the payload. 
                                    // On Amazon FireOS all custom attributes are contained within payload
                                    var soundfile = e.soundname || e.payload.sound;
                                    // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                                    // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
                                    var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+ soundfile);
                            my_media.play();
                        }
                        else
                        {   // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                            if (e.coldstart)
                                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                            else
                            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                        }

                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
                        //android only
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
                        //amazon-fireos only
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> TIMESTAMP: ' + e.payload.timeStamp + '</li>');
                    break;

                    case 'error':
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
                    break;

                    default:
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
                    break;
                }
            }

            function tokenHandler (result) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: '+ result +'</li>');
                // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
                // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
            }

            function successHandler (result) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:'+ result +'</li>');
            }

            function errorHandler (error) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:'+ error +'</li>');
            }

            document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);
         </script>
        <div id="home">
            <div id="app-status-div">
                <ul id="app-status-ul">
                    <li>Cordova PushNotification Plugin Demo</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: how can i store all registered token

Comment: and i am using android

Comment: Android And iOS  support this Plugin. And you want to not need to store registered token. this registered token you have to post using AJAx throw in your data base.

Answer (score 0):

How to POST your registered token(e.regid) on server are bellow.
and important note your e.regid it's know as GCM ID.

```
 if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
     {
         var userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');   
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '' + globURL + 'addgcm.php?user_id='+userId+'&gcm_id='+e.regid+'',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){

               }
            });   
        // alert(regid);
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
       // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
       // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                        console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
     }
```